# Eucalyptus 4.0 euca-describe-images returns null results

Tags: eucalyptus

Fresh install of Eucalyptus 4.0.  When I run  euca-describe-images no results are returned.  Euca-describe-services indicates all services are enabled with the exception of SERVICE imaging and SERVICE loadbalancing .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any images installed? If there is no image installed in your cloud it is supposed to show nothing iirc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install any images? (See `euca-install-image` and `euca-import-instance`.) It is expected for imaging and load-balacing services to not be enabled until they are installed (See `euca-install-imaging-worker` and `euca-install-load-balancer`.).